# gcf() makes the first figure size inconsistent with the rest

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am producing a series of figures to make a movie.

I found the first figure always looks a bit different, if I use `fig = plt.gcf()`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([-1+ float(i)*0.1616 for i in range(100)])
x, y = np.meshgrid( x, x) 

for t in range(3):

  fig = plt.gcf()     
  #fig = plt.figure() 
  fig.set_size_inches(9,6)

  plt.subplot(1,2,1,aspect='equal',title='t=%g'%t)
  plt.pcolormesh(x, y, x+y)

  plt.subplot(1,2,2,aspect='equal',title='t=%g'%t)
  plt.pcolormesh(x, y, x+2*y)

  plt.tight_layout()
  plt.savefig( 'series%g.png'%t, format = 'png')
```

**Result:**

See the anomition [series of figures gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJrWx.gif)

**Conclusion:**

I am satisfied with `fig = plt.figure()` instead. I jus curious why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the figures in a loop have identical size

**1) gcf() and plt.close()**

If you want use `gcf()` in a loop, remember add `plt.close()` in the end, the figures will be same size

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([-1+ float(i)*0.1616 for i in range(100)])
x, y = np.meshgrid( x, x) 

for t in range(3):

  plt.clf()
  plt.gcf().set_size_inches(9,6) # should also use plt.close()

  plt.subplot(1,2,1,aspect='equal',title='t=%g'%t)
  plt.pcolormesh(x, y, x+y)

  plt.subplot(1,2,2,aspect='equal',title='t=%g'%t)
  plt.pcolormesh(x, y, x+2*y)

  plt.tight_layout()
  plt.savefig( 'series%g_2.png'%t, format = 'png')
  plt.close()
```

**2) plt.figure()**

`plt.figure()` also works well

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([-1+ float(i)*0.1616 for i in range(100)])
x, y = np.meshgrid( x, x) 

for t in range(3):

  plt.clf()
  #plt.gcf().set_size_inches(9,6) # should also use plt.close()
  plt.figure(figsize=(9,6))

  plt.subplot(1,2,1,aspect='equal',title='t=%g'%t)
  plt.pcolormesh(x, y, x+y)

  plt.subplot(1,2,2,aspect='equal',title='t=%g'%t)
  plt.pcolormesh(x, y, x+2*y)

  plt.tight_layout()
  plt.savefig( 'sequece_figure_%g.png'%t, format = 'png')
  plt.close()
```